# What is difference between MSOLAP.5 and MSOLAP.6. Does SQL Server 2014 support MSOLAP.5?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

```
Openrowset('MSOLAP.5', 'DATA SOURCE=XYZ;Initial Catalog=PQR';)
```

I am upgrading SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server 2014. I upgraded all SSIS packages successfully. I upgraded all databases solution for SQL Server 2014. But during deployment of database (dacpac) on the SQL Server 2014, we faced an error:

```
Error SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 7403, Level 16, State 1, Procedure ABCD, Line 45 The OLE DB provider "MSOLAP.5" has not been registered.
Line 45- FROM OPENROWSET('MSOLAP.5','DATA SOURCE=XYZ;Initial Catalog=PQR;',... )
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask][http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I am upgrading SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server 2014. I upgraded all SSIS packages successfully. I upgraded all databases solution for SQL Server 2014. But during deployment of database (dacpac) on SQL Server 2014, We got below error - SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 7403, Level 16, State 1, Procedure usp_PPD_CDPPartners, Line 45 The OL
E DB provider "MSOLAP.5" has not been registered.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server 2014 support MSOLAP.6. but SQL Server 2014 PowerPivot workbooks use MSOLAP.5. If MSOLAP.5 is not installed on the computer running Excel Services, Excel Services cannot load the data models.

The providers for SQL Server are backward compatible. Therefore, if a provider tries to retrieve data from a data source server, and the version of the data source server corresponds to a version of the provider that is later than the version of the provider that is installed, the provider may experience certain issues. However, if the version of the data source server corresponds to a version of the provider that is earlier than the version of the provider that is installed, the provider can retrieve data from the data source server. We recommend that you install the version of MSOLAP that matches the latest version of the data source server that you are using. 
We can check MSOLAP on the server
exec master..xp_regread 'HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT', 'MSOLAP.5'
exec master..xp_regread 'HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT', 'MSOLAP.6'

For migration of SQL Server 2014,
Change MSOLAP.5 to MSOLAP.6 in all Stored procedure, build solution and deploy.